# connecting groovy to sql server

Tags: groovy, jtds

I am trying to connect a simple groovy script to the DB.

Code:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
class GroovySqlExample2{
  static void main(String[] args) {
    def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:sqlserver://MYSERVERIP", "uname",
           "pwd", "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver")
    sql.eachRow("select * from word"){ 
      println it.spelling + " ${it.part_of_speech}"
    }
  }
}
```

I've placed jtds-1.2.3.jar inside C:\groovy-1.6.3\lib folder but the above code keeps complaining:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: Though not related to your error just wanted to point out that the url should be jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://MYSERVERIP, the one you have listed is incorrect since it's missing the jtds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a GROOVY_HOME Environment variable set to c:\groovy-1.6.3

Answer (score 4):

Use Grape and set `systemClassLoader=true`

```
@Grapes(
    @Grab(group='net.sourceforge.jtds', module='jtds', version='1.3.1')
)
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
import groovy.sql.*
// http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#urlFormat
def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://MYSERVERIP", "uname",
       "pwd", "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver")
sql.eachRow("select * from word"){ 
  println it.spelling + " ${it.part_of_speech}"
}
```

Comment: the jdbc url should be "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://MYSERVERIP", or a No Suitable Driver exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

Download jtds-1.2.2.jar and add the below line in your groovy script 
before def sql.

```
this.class.classLoader.rootLoader.addURL( new URL("file:/C:\\jtds-1.2.2.jar"))
```